# check image in UIImageView is not a placeholder image and append to UIImage array

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I have set a placeholder image for my image views. The user can change these to a photo from their library. Once they have done this, they can then upload these images to a database. The user can upload a single image or many, either way, they are uploaded as an [UIImage]. However, I do not want the placeholder images to be uploaded.

I have managed to achieve this, but in a very ungraceful manner. I have done this by firstly subclassing UIImageView, adding a property called isSet and setting all my image views to this class:

```
class ItemImageViewClass: UIImageView {

//keeps track of whether the image has changed from the placeholder image.
var isSet = Bool()
```

}

and then when the image has been set after the user has selected an image, the isSet property is set to true.

To check if the image in the image view has been changed from the placeholder image (i.e. `isSet == true`) I used the following code:

```
var imageArray: [UIImage]? = nil

    if imageViewOne.isSet {
    guard let mainImage = imageViewOne.image else {return}
        if (imageArray?.append(mainImage)) == nil {
            imageArray = [mainImage]
        }
    }
    if imageViewTwo.isSet {
        guard let imageTwo = imageViewTwo.image else {return}
        if (imageArray?.append(imageTwo)) == nil {
            imageArray = [imageTwo]
        }
    }

    guard imageArray != nil else {
        print("imageArray is nil")
        alertMessage("Hey!", message: "Please add some images!")
        return
    }
```

When at least one image has been selected, the array will be saved to the database.

This seems like a very messy way to do it; subclassing UIImageView and having to check that each image has changed using a series of `if` statements. Is there a more elegant way to achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution by extending `UIImageView` to avoid subclassing. And, using `filter` and `flatMap` to by pass the if-statements. This requires that you use the same reference to the placeholder image for each `UIImageView`.

```
// In this example, the placeholder image is global but it doesn't have to be.
let placeHolderImage = UIImage() 

extension UIImageView {

  // Check to see if the image is the same as our placeholder 
  func isPlaceholderImage(_ placeHolderImage: UIImage = placeHolderImage) -> Bool {
    return image == placeHolderImage
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
let imageViewOne = UIImageView(image: placeHolderImage)
imageViewOne.isPlaceholderImage() // true

let imageViewTwo = UIImageView()
imageViewTwo.isPlaceholderImage() // false

let imageViewThree = UIImageView()
imageViewThree.image = UIImage(named: "my-image")
imageViewThree.isPlaceholderImage() // false
```

Filter and map for images that are not placeholders or nil:

```
let imageArray = [imageViewOne, imageViewTwo, imageViewThree].filter 
{ !$0.isPlaceholderImage() }.flatMap { $0.image }

print(imageArray) // imageViewThree.image
```

If the extension does not work for your requirements, I would definitely consider "filter and flatMap" to avoid that if-statement.

Comment: Thanks for your response, definitely better than my approach. I'm struggling to wrap my head around the final section of code. I understand that `.filter` in this use case will remove those image views where the return value for `.isPlaceholderImage` is false, but what does .`flatMap { $0.image }` do here? Am i right in thinking that it is accessing the image of the element and adding it to the imageArray? I would've thought `.map` would be used for that?

Comment: flatMap eliminates any optionals from the array

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a new UI component for your needs with a background UIImageView(placeholder) and an optional foreground UIImageView (user selected). Then just check for the existence of the optional foreground UIImageView as you can rely upon this being the UIImageView containing the user chosen image.